# How to only get UserID from message.guild.members.fetch() in discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get a random winner for prizes and I would like to take the whole object variable and just sorta isolate the whole thing so i just get a list of the UserID's

Heres an example of what I get when I do `console.log(message.guild.members.fetch())`:

```js
Promise {
  Collection [Map] {
    '123456789012345678' => GuildMember {        
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1234567890123,
      lastMessageID: '012345678901234567',       
      lastMessageChannelID: '012345678901234567',
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array]
    },
    '234567890123456789' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [User],
      joinedTimestamp: 1234567890123,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array]
    },
    '345678901234567890' => GuildMember {
      guild: [Guild],
      user: [ClientUser],
      joinedTimestamp: 1234567890123,
      lastMessageChannelID: null,
      premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
      deleted: false,
      _roles: [Array]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to only get the `123456789012345678` part of the `'123456789012345678' => GuildMember {`line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `keys` method (inherited from `Map`):

```js
message.guild.messages.fetch().then(members => {
  const userIDs = [...members.keys()]
  // Do something with the IDs here
})
```

With async/await:

```js
const userIDs = [...(await message.guild.messages.fetch()).keys()]
// Do something with the IDs here
```